# Dynamically updating WPF data template

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

I have the below Button XAML

```
<Button Name="btnLogoff" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Click="btnToolbar_Click" CommandParameter="LOGOFF"
                    Template="{DynamicResource ToolbarButton}"
                        Style="{StaticResource ToolbarButtonDisplay}" z:ButtonProperties.Image="..\..\Resources\Images\Logoff.GIF" Content="Logoff">
                </Button>
```

ButtonProperties is as follows

```
public class ButtonProperties
    {
        public static ImageSource GetImage(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (ImageSource) obj.GetValue(ImageProperty);
        } 

        public static void SetImage(DependencyObject obj, ImageSource value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(ImageProperty, value);
        } 

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Image", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ButtonProperties), new UIPropertyMetadata((ImageSource)null));
    }
```

Which works fine, to give me a template for buttons I can use throughout the app that have an image and text component.

What I want to be able to do is change the style dynamically from ToolbarButton to ToolbarButtonRed on certain background thread methods, such as notifying the user that an event is about to occur, the button will change to a red style. Both styles are in the resources of the XAML page but I cant figure out how to change the Template programmatically.

I have tried..

```
        public DataTemplate AlarmTemplate
        {
            get
            {
                if (_alarmTemplate != null)
                    return _alarmTemplate;
                else
                    return (DataTemplate)_parent.FindResource("ToolbarButton");
            }
            set
            {
                _alarmTemplate = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AlarmTemplate");
            }
        }


private void SetAlarmIcon(bool red)
        {
            if (red)
                AlarmTemplate = (DataTemplate)_parent.FindResource("ToolbarButtonRed");
            else
                AlarmTemplate = (DataTemplate)_parent.FindResource("ToolbarButton");
        }
```

and binding the XAML as such

But no joy. The button doesnt even display at all. Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

Style below

```
<Style x:Key="ToolbarButtonDisplay" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=(Windows:ButtonProperties.Image), RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}" Margin="0,2,0,0" Width="32"/>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="9" FontWeight="Normal" FontFamily="Arial" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="2,2,2,2">
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"></ContentPresenter>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsEnabled}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ToolbarButtonRed}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Final update - I got a trigger to work as below

```
<Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DisplayToolbar}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource ToolbarButtonRed}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
```

By just using an arbitrary property on the datacontext (DisplayToolbar) as I am not sure how to do this specific to a button. To explain, I have about 30 buttons on the page, which all use the same style and hence the same trigger so the above code will set all 30 to red. I need a way for each button to workout whether IT and IT ALONE should be red, so I'm thinking along the lines of setting some property of a button control if there is one I can use, and have the data trigger look at the buttons properties, not the datacontexts. What is the syntax to bind to the buttons own properties rather than the datacontext?

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as setting the Style property to the value located with FindResource.

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { btnLogoff.Style = (Style)FindResource("ToolbarButtonRed"); });
```

The dispatcher invoke is being used here because you can't set dependency properties on a control from a background thread.

Based on the comment below, the control template can be set in exactly the same way.

```
 Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { btnLogoff.Template = (ControlTemplate)FindResource("ToolbarButtonRed"); });
```

Comment: Sorry I should have specified, ToolbarButton and ToolbarButtonRed are ControlTemplates, not styles

Comment: If I'm understanding the problem correctly the edit should be what you need.

Comment: I'm trying to do it via MVVM so avoiding direct btn property changes if possible, Id ideally like to update a dependency property which would then affect the GUI. Can you not update the dependency property on the GUI thread by using dispatcher invoke? As that is what I did up above initially but that wasnt working. Alternatively, I've posted the buttons style definition above and added in a block for doing it via a data trigger, is this possible? And what mistake have I made as it isn't seeming to work.